# :hover and TD borders

Tags: css

I got a table with some top and bottom borders.. But the :hover class doesn't work as I want it to..

In some cases I got an extra class on the TD's and when the mouse is moved over only the bottom border changes

I have made a jsfiddle here to demonstrate:

```
td {
    border:1px solid #99bfe3;
    border-left:0px;
    border-right:0px;
    padding:5px;
    vertical-align:top;
}

tr:hover > td {
    background:#cae5fd;
    border:1px #375877 solid;
    border-left:0px;
    border-right:0px;
}

td.test {
    background:#9deea4;
    border:1px #51a357 solid;
    border-left:0px;
    border-right:0px;
}

tr:hover > td.test {
    background:#7fda86;
    border:1px #265c2b solid;
    border-left:0px;
    border-right:0px;
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="test">cell</td>
        <td>cell<br>hmm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="test">cell</td>
        <td class="test">cell<br>hmm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell<br>hmm</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VRv3f/

How can you make both the top and bottom borders to react on :hover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be considered cheating, but you could use a `SPAN` (or `DIV`) inside your `TD.test` and then deploy negative margins.

**NOTE**: This will break if two cells have different heights, since the `SPAN`/`DIV` will not expand to the new calculated height of the row. The below example gets around this by setting the border on the bottom of the cell (which works fine), and then setting the top border on the negative margin `SPAN` within it, while zeroing out the padding top, left and right on the cell and adding it to the `SPAN`.

```
tr > td {
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #99bfe3;
    vertical-align: top;
}

tr:hover {
    background: #cae5fd;
}

td.test {
    background: #b1f0b6;
}

tr:hover > td.test {
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    background: #8de194;
}

tr:hover > td.test span {
    display: block;
    margin: -1px 0;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px 5px 1px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="test"><span>cell</span></td>
        <td>cell<br>hmm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="test"><span>cell</span></td>
        <td class="test"><span>cell<br>hmm</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell<br>hmm</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/82bRU/18/

Comment: Not sure why WebKit wouldn't work; it's not anything exotic. Are you testing in Safari? (It does work in FF, although Chrome doesn't comply...)

Comment: @mu is too short - Apparently it needs to be positioned: http://jsfiddle.net/82bRU/11/ Not sure about Safari, but this works in Chrome Latest.

Comment: Also IE9 (IE7/8 works but with a slight shift that could be fixed with a conditional CSS declaration).

Comment: I'm not positioning a `TABLE` cell, but a `SPAN`.

Comment: have updated my question.. if a TD with `test` class contains a <br> or is higher then the rest of the row it doesn't work

Comment: I can see what you mean (even though your edit didn't use the method above). See: http://jsfiddle.net/82bRU/17/ And min-height doesn't appear to work.

Comment: and how can you make the borders change even without the `test` class also? see my question

Comment: @clarkk - I don't understand what you mean by "without the test class also". Do you mean make all cells in a row change on hover?

Comment: yes.. but if the TD don't has the `test` class the border has to be another color

Answer (score 0):

It works if I use `border-collapse:separate;` like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="test">row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**css**

```
table{
    border-collapse:separate;
}

td {
    padding:5px;
    border-left: 1px solid white;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom:1px solid #99bfe3;
    border-top: 1px solid #99bfe3;
    border-collapse:separate;
}

td:hover {
    background:#cae5fd;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

td.test {
    background:#b1f0b6;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/82bRU/13/

Fyi... some of your `tr`s were not closed either.

Comment: Jason, your example will separate the lines, but there's actually four lines now, with the TD above and the TD below.